# uncaught type error :undefiened is not a function for JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am using json to send a list of songs to my table.The json response is coming fine till the controller url.But when I try to iterate through it and put the details in my table I am getting this error.

```
  $(window).load(function(){
        $.get("/MusicPlayer/getSongList", function(data){
         var library = data;
         listSongs(library);
    });
}); 


 function listSongs(library){
 var table = $("#table");
 var row;
 $("#table tbody").remove();
 library.forEach(function(song){ ***/*this is the line where there is error. */*** 
     row = $("<tr></tr>");
        $("<td />").addClass("song-select").append($("<input  
        />").attr({type:"checkbox",class:"checkbox",value:song.title})).appendTo(row);
        $("<td>"+song.title+"</td>").appendTo(row);
        $("<td>"+song.album+"</td>").appendTo(row);
        $("<td>"+song.artist+"</td>").appendTo(row);
        $("<td>"+song.rating+"</td>").appendTo(row);
        $("<td>"+song.composer+"</td>").appendTo(row);
        $("<td>"+song.genre+"</td>").appendTo(row);
        row.click(viewFunction());
        row.appendTo(table);
 });


 [
{
    "title": "15 - Jacob's Theme.mp3",
    "album": "The Twilight Saga - Eclipse",
    "artist": "Howard Shore",
    "rating": "2",
    "composer": "carter ruwell",
    "genre": "Soundtrack"
},
{
    "title": "07_-_Vennante.mp3",
    "album": "Andala Rakshasi (2012)",
    "artist": "Ranjith",
    "rating": "0",
    "composer": "Rathan",
    "genre": "TeluguMusic"
},
{
    "title": "08. One Simple Idea.mp3",
    "album": "Inception (OST)",
    "artist": "Hans Zimmer",
    "rating": "0",
    "composer": "null",
    "genre": "?????????"
}
   ]
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` in the callback. What shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `json` response is a **string** in a very specific format, but still just a string.

Before being able to use it as Javascript data you need to parse it using `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to `$.parseJSON`, since `library` should be a JSON formatted string, not really an array.

```
$.parseJSON(library).forEach(function(song){ .....
```

Answer (score 0):

json object does not have `forEach` function defined for it.

use for loop :

```
for(var song in library) {
   console.log(song, result[song]);
}
```

or with jquery `each`:

```
$.each(library, function(key, value) {

});​
```

`forEach` is just for simple arrays and in the environment that supports `ECMAScript5`.
take a look at this too : [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)